# Why are my links not u being centered under my image?

Tags: html

Anyone can tell me why my links aren't being centered under my image? The center tag worked for my image but not for the links any clue why? This is messing me up a bit.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>



<head>


      <title>PEllisFitness</title>

      <link href="feel.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

   </head>



<body background="wayback.jpg">
      <header>
         <center><img src="Fitness Logo.jpg" alt="Fitness Logo" align="middle" style="border:5px solid black"/></center>

      </header>

      <center>
      <nav>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="Diet.html">Diet Plans</a></li>
            <li><a href="Mass.html">Mass Guide</a></li>
            <li><a href="Cutting.html">Cuttin Guide</a></li>
            <li><a href="About.html">About Me</a></li>
            <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact Info</a></li>
         </ul>
      </nav>

      </center>

   </body>

</html>
```

Comment: ...where did you get the idea to use a `<center>` tag?  That's super [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center).  Are you getting started on this with any particular tutorial or learning material?

Comment: No, im actually workin on my final aha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using **CSS** for this.
The `<center>` tag is deprecated.
At the moment, you are centering the whole list, not the list items, which may cause the issue. So if you want your links centered, you need to wrap every single `<li>` inside a `<center>`. Hope, this helps.

A better solution would be, to add CSS to the `<ul>`. Change it to

```
<ul style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center;">
```

This will make the list a [CSS-Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) with the child elements displayed in a column and centered.

Comment: i did this in css and it didnt work li{
 
 text-align:center;
}

Comment: @phillipswag text-align only alignes text inside a single element, or elements which are displayed as `inline`,`inline-block` or another text-like display type. Therefore it can't work here.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a table instead of a list? You can place the links in a table, center the table, and center the text in the table.

Comment: Using tables to format works often enough, but really should be avoided, as tables should be used to present data, not to format webpages

Answer (score 0):

Use below style at your UL tag for center alignment

```
<ul class="centerNavList">
```

and

```
<style>
.centerNavList {
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 12px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use center tag just because  sometimes  doesn't work properly.But the custom css never beatray ;) . hope it helps

```
ul{
position:relative;
display: inline-block;  
list-style: none;
width:100%;
text-align: center;
margin: auto;
padding: 0;
}
```

see the fiddle 
[center Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Asifuzzaman/85gt9c4u/)